# Show vertices behind other mesh

Tags: vertices

I have 2 separate meshes. Is there any way to show vertices through other meshes? I know about wireframe, but want to work in that way.

[image: Vertices under mesh]

P.S. I really tried to find a solution. But haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **Toggle X-Ray** Option in the upper right corner.

[image]